# Blender 2.8 (Python) - what does this console error mean

Tags: python

It occurs when I am printing to disk a .jpg image of my scene:

```
AL lib:  (EE) ALCmmdevPlayback_mixerProc:  WaitForSingleObjectEx error:  0x102
```

My script just stalls out after the error message appears.

Anything I can do about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error is coming from your OpenAL (Open Audio Library) which encounters a problem. It may be unrelated to your issue though. You can temporarily disable the sound system by starting Blender from the terminal with the `-noaudio` flag or set *Audio Device* to *Null* in the preferences (*Edit > Preferences*).

If your script still fails to write to disk it's likely a bug in your script and not caused by a problem with OpenAL. You can revert the changes in the preferences if that's the case. Should the problem disappear with the suggested settings, then it would be nice if could write a bug report (*Help > Report a Bug* in Blender).

[image: Preferences.]